# How to create a module code in node.js with the given filetree?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, code-generation

So I want to get all the file paths from a given folder and all of its children and create a JS/TS file with that data as a module

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

var walkSync = function (dir, filelist) {
    files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    filelist = filelist || {};
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        if (fs.statSync(dir + file).isDirectory()) {
            filelist = walkSync(dir + file + "/", filelist);
        } else {
            const basename = path.basename(dir);

            if (filelist[basename] === undefined) {
                filelist[basename] = {};
            }
            filelist[basename][file.split(".")[0].toUpperCase()] = dir + file;
        }
    });
    return filelist;
};
```

Here's what I have done up till now. It generates output something like this:

```
{
  Scripts: {
    CONFIG: './Assets/Scripts/config.ts',
    MAIN: './Assets/Scripts/main.ts'
  },
  Scenes: {
    GAMESCENE: './Assets/Scripts/Scenes/GameScene.ts',
    LOADSCENE: './Assets/Scripts/Scenes/LoadScene.ts',
    MAINMENUSCENE: './Assets/Scripts/Scenes/MainMenuScene.ts'
  },
  Sprites: {
    ARROW: './Assets/Sprites/arrow.png',
    BUTTON: './Assets/Sprites/button.png',
    CHARACTER: './Assets/Sprites/character.png',
    TILES: './Assets/Sprites/tiles.png'
  }
}
```

And from all this information I want to create a separate js/ts file containing all this information in this form:

```
export const ASSET_PATHS = {
    ball: "Assets/Sprites/orange.png",
    platform: "Assets/Sprites/paddle1.png",
    crate: "Assets/Sprites/crate.png",
    background: "Assets/Sprites/background.png",
};
```

Comment: Where do the values in `ASSET_PATHS` come from?

Comment: This is the sample output I want to have as a result right now I have typed them on my own into a file